# How to make right query to vTiger CRM API

Tags: php, api, vtiger

I got an sql query:

```
$vtiger->query('*', 'Products', "(productname LIKE '%$name%' OR description LIKE '%$name%') AND cf_1007 = 'Ready'", null, 50, null);
```

(using https://github.com/sumocoders/vtiger-api). It has an WHERE clause. How to make it right? (current query throws exception). I need to take all rows where productname or description contains %name% and where cell cf_1007 = "Ready".

UPD: answer from vTiger API (forgot to add it here)

```
{"success":false,"error":{"code":"QUERY_SYNTAX_ERROR","message":"Syntax Error on line 1: token '(' Unexpected PARENOPEN((), expected one of: COLUMNNAME"}}
```

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: your code seems legit, follow @Egl question.

Comment: @Egl added to question, forgot to add

Comment: Check out my answer, I hope it would help.

Comment: there's a syntax error due to '('. Try removing it, changing (A OR B) AND C for A AND C OR B AND C.

Comment: @Egl thanks, that's the best way to evade it

Comment: If it works, then I'm going to add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error due to the first `(`.

Try removing it, changing

```
(A OR B) AND C
```

for

```
A AND C OR B AND C
```

Answer (score 0):

I dug deeper regarding this issue and found the following:
The API you're using sends a request to the VTIGER web service. There's nothing wrong in the API and your usage seems to be fine. So, next station would be to check the webservice documentations.

Then I came across [this page](http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html) and found the following:

```
SELECT * | <column_list> | <count(*)> FROM <object> [WHERE
<conditionals>] [ORDER BY <column_list>] [LIMIT [<m>, ] <n>]
```

Notice the description of the  part:

> `<condition_operations>` or `<in_clauses>` or `<like_clauses>` separated by
>   ‘and’ or ‘or’ operators these are processed from left to right. The
>   **are no grouping that is bracket operators**.

So it seems that you can't use the `(field1=val1 OR field2=val2) AND field3=val3` format. You should use `field1=val1 OR field2=val AND field3=val3`.

Comment: Thanks, but...I knew it, that's why I'm here :) It isnt working when I start my script. When I started my script without brakets in query string, I got wrong results of my query (there's so much strings where last field is not equal to 'Ready'). Idk how to group my query in that case :(